# recursive function stack overflow

Tags: visual-studio-2008, recursion, stack-overflow, backtracking

This function takes a string `wild` containing '*' and '?' wild cards, and replaces the wildcards  with possible chars from a tree database with `nodeT *w`. `out` holds a temporary string. Each candidates is added to a referenced bst.

```
void Lexicon::matchRegExpHelper(nodeT *w, string wild, Set<string> &matchSet, string out)
{   
    if (wild == "") matchSet.add(out);

    else {
        if (wild[0] != '*' || wild[0] != '?') { //this parses up to the wildcard, earlier versions used a position parameter and looped through the prefix chars recursively
            for (int j = 0; j < w->alpha.size(); j++)
                if (wild[0] == w->alpha[j].letter) matchRegExpHelper(w->alpha[j].next, wild.substr(1), matchSet, out+=wild[0]);
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < w->alpha.size(); i++) { 
                if (wild[0] == '?') matchRegExpHelper(w->alpha[i].next, wild.substr(1), matchSet, out+=w->alpha[i].letter);//follow path
                else { //logically, wild[0] == '*' must be true
                    if (ontLength == (wild.length() + out.length())) matchRegExpHelper(w->alpha[i].next, wild.substr(1), matchSet, out+=w->alpha[i].letter); //ontology is full, treat like a '?'
                    else matchRegExpHelper(w->alpha[i].next, wild.substr(1), matchSet, out+=(w->alpha[i].letter+'*')); //keep adding chars
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When the first wildcard is reached the function starts over - I have tried rewriting this with the for loops, without the loops, and in differing 'prune' approaches. I am missing something basic and suspect this is a backtracking issue. Eventually the stack overflows.

Question: 1) what am I missing conceptually, and 2) how do I fix this function?

version without for loop - the test case is a bit different but similar, I'd have to test it to find it again

```
else {
            if (wild[0] == '?'){
                matchRegExpHelper(w, wild, ++pos, matchSet, out);//return and check next path
                matchRegExpHelper(w->alpha[pos].next, wild.substr(1), 0, matchSet, out+=w->alpha[pos].letter);//follow path
            }
            if (wild[0] == '*'){
                matchRegExpHelper(w, wild, ++pos, matchSet, out);//return and check next path
                if (ontLength == (wild.length() + out.length()))matchRegExpHelper(w->alpha[pos].next, wild.substr(1), 0, matchSet, out+=w->alpha[pos].letter); //ontology is full, treat like a '?'
                else matchRegExpHelper(w->alpha[pos].next, wild.substr(1), 0, matchSet, out+=(w->alpha[pos].letter+'*')); //keep adding chars
            }
            if (wild[0] == w->alpha[pos].letter) matchRegExpHelper(w->alpha[pos].next, wild.substr(1), 0, matchSet, out+=wild[0]);  

            matchRegExpHelper(w, wild, ++pos, matchSet, out);//check next path
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < w->alpha.size(); i++) matchRegExpHelper(w->alpha[i].next, wild.substr(1), 0, matchSet, out+=wild[0]);//step over char
```

the for loop at the end was an attempt to fix the overflow, i thought maybe there was no case for some threads, but I wanted those to prune, so not sure what to do

Comment: Did you try to use the debugger?

Comment: @Basile_Starynkevitch maybe I don't know what the dubugger is, but I pressed the green arrow that said 'start debugging' - so I think the answer is yes.

Comment: You need to learn how to use your development tools for debugging. Taking time to read some documentation won't harm. You'll need to put breakpoints and to look into backtraces.

Comment: I will search for 'backtraces' - I am not a programmer, this is for my graduate experiment and this is more or less the last function I need to rewrite. I put breakpoints throughout this and followed the path, but I have not seen a tool for backtraces.

Comment: Each time it reaches the wildcard it starts again from where the function is called. Also, the first couple of webpages I read were confusing - I still have no idea what a backtrace is. Maybe something with the call stack, but reviewing the call stack was not much help, it is just the same function over and over.

Comment: It looks like the loops that I wanted pruned are continuing through the function and then in the preceding function they call the next function, which returns the bst to the previous function, where it then call the same function again and repeats the process.  If this function returned something rather than modified a referenced memory then I would check for 'return' but in this case I have no idea what to do; I tried 'break' and other ways of closing the bottom of the function.

Comment: Did you read answers from Picarus or me?

Comment: @Basile_Starynkevitch I looked in some function that have a similar form and they use `return` at the end of the logic gates.

Comment: @Basile_Starynkevitch, yes - and changing the logic `||` to `&&` did not fix the issue, although you are correct. And, I understand putting breakpoints, and querying value of variables, but I had never heard of asking for backtraces,

Comment: I solved it, there needs two `return;`, one after the termination condition to terminate and another at the end to catch pruned threads. It took awhile but I remember this issue from before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were three issues with this code:

@Basile_Starynkevitch noted the importance of using the debugger to follow the path - in this case with VS2008, the stack allowed parsing the steps and noting the path moving back through several functions.

@Picarus correctly noted the error in the terminating condition

These solutions led to finding:

the solution, this void function requires two `return;`, one after the termination condition to terminate and another at the end to catch pruned threads. from reading several websites, it seems that a `return;` in a void function is unusual, but this case with the recursion and multiple paths, it was required.

Answer (score 2):

this condition is always true:
(wild[0] != '*' || wild[0] != '?')

As any character is different from one of the two, maybe you meant (wild[0] != '*' && wild[0] != '?')

I hope this helps you to make some progress...

Also conceptually, I usually don't use 'for' inside a recursive function, try to rewrite it without using 'for' probably it will be clearer, maybe not efficient but once it works you can start fine tuning the algorithm..

Comment: weird, it seems like and either/or logic, but you are correct. Is there a reason to avoid for loops in recursion, I have a version I wrote earlier that does not use the for loop - it also has the logic error.

Comment: it still overflows, those are good but they did not fix the issue - I think this is a backtracking issue or an run-over from the function not terminating loose loops. I had this issue back when I took CS and the TA explained it, that was in '09 though

Comment: The idea of recursive functions is that they work because every iteration (new call), solves a piece of the problem and the next takes this as precondition or postcondition, depending on the kind of recursivity.

Comment: In your case, if you did a 'for' based on the size of the string but when you process one position of the string the size of the string changed, the algorithm would fail.Note I am saying 'did' since I am not sure it's your case.

Answer (score 1):

Every recursion should have a base terminating condition.

I've got the feeling that

```
 if (wild[0] != '*' || wild[0] != '?')
```

is wrong (that test is always true, because a character cannot be at the same time a `'*'` and a `'?'`), it should be a conjunction `&&` not a disjunction `||`

But as I said in a comment, you really should **learn how to use a [debugger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger)** (i.e. putting [breakpoints](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breakpoint), asking for [backtraces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtrace), querying value of variables).

Familiarity with debugging is a skill that will be valuable for all your life, beyond this particular program (or homework).

Comment: this is not homework - graduate, like Dr Evils homework maybe; unless I am the professor then maybe it is homework - actually motel work right now :)

Comment: @Basile_Starynkevitch, I have be rereading your comments and I cannot see the solution you have made? Also, I did not mean to claim that i only want to get this task done and move on, of course life knowledge is valuable and we all will be writing software throughout our life, I did not intend to give the impression you seem to have picked up.